# How are the functions for rational motion defined?

Tags: rational-functions, spline, projectile-motion

I'm trying to implement a program using C++ that could determine a B-spline curve which would represent rational motion between given control positions (following along with Juttler and Wagner's *Spatial Rational B-Spline Motion* paper, [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Michael_Wagner12/publication/242795605_Computer-Aided_Design_With_Spatial_Rational_B-Spline_Motions/links/53f02b510cf26b9b7dcdf633.pdf)).

In the paper the authors define the motion curve as being based on three parameters, $v_0(t)$, $v_{0...3}(t)$ and $d_{0...3}(t)$. But where do these parameters come from? Are they simply defined by the transformation from one control point to another, just parameterized with time? I'm really stuck on this, and am having difficulty proceeding forward. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The paper says "According to [13, 15] any piecewise rational motion M(t) of degree k possesses a representation" right before the table that references those parameters. Did you look at the references [13] and [15]?

Comment: I did, and unfortunately, both of the references are in German so they're not very helpful.

Comment: Even if you use Google translate?

Comment: If I use Google translate, I am not able to find results. I have a feeling it's because the translation is incorrect.

Comment: I found and was able to have google translate [15] here: http://d-nb.info/942086791/04, but it's only table of contents. I also found [13], and it has complete text (in German): http://www.ag.jku.at/pubs/uzr93.pdf. Google translate sort of worked - it looks like it doesn't understand PDFs and just translates everything including binary. Using translator built into MS Word shows the tables with the parameters but no text. My only remaining suggestions are 1) contact author of paper you referenced (at Drexler U) 2) find someone or some service to translate [13] to English.